# How do I render a custom form on a view page?

Tags: views, forms, 8, routes

In my module's `routing.yml` file I set the form path to a path which also shows a view page. But on that path the form does not get displayed, only the view.

When I change the path in the `routing.yml` it works, so I guess views somehow overrides/ ignores my form.

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you could do the reverse, create a view block and place it on your form page.

Comment: Yes, a route required by a page view and a custom route will always conflict because there can only be one route. Does the custom form affect the view or do you want to display different types of content in a custom layout (using blocks, panels, etc...)?

Comment: @mradcliffe i think its best when i provide a custom block with my form and just add it to the view page via block overview :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only possible to display one "page" on a url, so you can't both display a view and a form or any other "page" for that matter.

You have a few options:

1. Insert the form into the view (can be done with a global views handler)
2. Insert the form on the view page by exposing it as a block.
3. Insert the view on the form page by exposing it as a block.

Probably the easiest solution for you is to convert the view page to a view block and insert it on the form page. Views already has support for this, so you only need a few clicks in the interface to achieve this.